# should I count repeated words when I compute score of sentences in document analysis?

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, data-analysis

I am learning to analyze document with python with reference to book .When I read some code in the book, I feel puzzled, here the code is:
[Example 6. A document summarization algorithm based principally upon sentence detection and frequency analysis within sentences](https://rawgit.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/master/ipynb/html/Chapter%205%20-%20Mining%20Web%20Pages.html)

what makes me puzzle is this:

```
    s = [...words of sentence...]
    word_idx = []

    # For each word in the word list...
    for w in important_words:
        try:
            # Compute an index for where any important words occur in the sentence.

            word_idx.append(s.index(w))
        except ValueError, e: # w not in this particular sentence
            pass

    word_idx.sort()
```

why not use this:

```
        for i in range(len(s)):
            w = s[i]
            if w in important_words:
                word_idx.append(i)
```

the difference between them is that:
the former doesn't count repeated words while the latter counts, for example:

```
s = [u'fes', u'watch', u'\u2014', u'e-paper', u'watch', u',', u'including', u'strap', u'.']
```

the former print `[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]` while the latter print `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

so should I count repeated words when I compute score of sentences?

Comment: I'm puzzled why you get `..., 5, 6, ...` instead of `..., 4, 6, ...` :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla I am sorry I didn't speak clearly. `s[4] = u'watch'`, as you can see `s[2] = u'watch'` too, so the former algorithm will not append 4 to `word_idx`

Comment: Oops, you're right. I got the indexes wrong when counting in my head.

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that the first algorithm is a inefficient when you have lots of `important_words`. Your algorithm is more efficient but it does count words twice which doesn't seem right. Should `watch watch watch watch` get a higher score than `Bobby has a watch`?

The answer depends on your needs. There is no "best" solution when it comes to natural text analysis. Google has different needs when analyzing HTML pages than, say, an archaeologist.

So I think this boils down to: Is there a more efficient algorithm which produces the same result as the one from the book?

Yes: Use your code and put the words into `set()` to remove duplicates:

```
s = set(s)
```

Depending on your Python version, this step might reorder the words but I don't think this matters since the code from the book doesn't use `s` after the first loop.

If the order matters, you need to filter the list.

Comment: I am suspecting there are any problems in this algorithm, I think we should count the repeated words. In fact, I think the order is important too, because the code `total_words_in_cluster = c[-1] - c[0] + 1` depends on the order, so I don't think `s = set(s)` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If You continue reading [Example 6. A document summarization algorithm based principally upon sentence detection and frequency analysis within sentences](https://rawgit.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/master/ipynb/html/Chapter%205%20-%20Mining%20Web%20Pages.html),
 You will see the following line

```
for c in clusters:
    significant_words_in_cluster = len(c)
    total_words_in_cluster = c[-1] - c[0] + 1
    score = 1.0 * significant_words_in_cluster \
        * significant_words_in_cluster / total_words_in_cluster
```

, while c is the list You compared:

"the former print [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8] while the latter print [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]".

While "total_words_in_cluster" stays the same, for each list, "significant_words_in_cluster" differs. This influences the clusters "score".

The way the author creates the cluster list is a choice for futher computation. Your attempt seems legit on its own, i think.

Btw. Also the way the clusters are created,

```
if word_idx[i] - word_idx[i - 1] < CLUSTER_THRESHOLD:
     cluster.append(word_idx[i])
```

depend on the values on the idx_s list...

Comment: yes, this is exactly why I feel puzzled, I do think we need to count the repeated words when process document.